# Differences betwen "ahí", "allí", and "allá"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, deixis

I am confused with the uses of *ahí*, *allí*, and *allá*.

It seems they are used according to different situations.

Could you please tell me what are the differences are and provide some examples?

Comment: closely related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/what-is-the-difference-between-alli-and-ahi-there

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no strong differences between those words, at least in spoken language. There might be tiny differences according to the dictionary, but here are a few examples of their use, at least uses I can think of:

- *Ahí* and *allí* are basically the same, but *ahí* seems to be less used than *allí* (according to RAE, though I disagree). Both indicate a physical place.

  > Ahí está Juan.
  >
  > El accidente ocurrió allí.
- *Por ahí* is used to indicate a place that is close by, or a place that is undetermined altogether.

  > *Voy a caminar por ahí* is something like "I'm going for a walk around".
  >
  > *Por ahí se cuenta que...* means "It is said (around) that...", or "It is being said here and there that...", implying that a rumor *is* being spread, but without compromising with an actual location where this might've happened.
- On the other hand, *allí* indicates time, but *ahí* does not. That is the one difference between both words. I must say, however, that I have not heard that use much here in Chile. It might be common in other countries.

  > *Allí fue el trabajo* is the example in the dictionary. It means something like *the job was back then*, meaning a past time that should be clear from the context (the rest of the conversation).
- *Allá* indicates some place that could be far from you and a bit undetermined at the same time.

  > *Allá en Rusia*: "there in Russia".
  >
  > *Allá lejos*: "there, far away". Basically, you wouldn't say *allí* here, because, roughly speaking, you would use *allí* only when you refer to a place that you can point with your finger (*allí en la colina*: "there, over the hill").
- *Allá* also indicates time, but a remote past only.

  > *Allá en tiempo del Imperio Romano*.
  >
  > *Allá en la prehistoria*.
- Finally, there are a couple of uses of *allá* that do not apply to *allí* and *ahí*:

  > *El más allá* means "the underworld", in the sense of "the world beyond", not necessarily with a connotation of punishment (as in "hell"). When people die they go to the "más allá", and this could be heaven, hell or some other place or reality depending of one's beliefs.
  >
  > *Allá tú* means "have it your own way". For example, if two people are discussing a plan of action and one of them is absolutely determined to proceed in a specific manner, the other one might get tired of arguing and say *allá tú*, as in "I give up, have it your own way". Same with *allá él*, *allá ella*, *allá ellos*, *allá ustedes/vosotros* and *allá usted*.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I've seen that both "allí" y "allá" can refer to a distant specific place. But I just heard people say that sometimes only specific one could be used. I am still confused.

Comment: @Cadenza: Well, as for **when** certain words can or can't be used, that's not very precise, for a language evolves all the time according to how people use its words. Personally, I would not use *allí* to refer to a very distant place, and I think it is incorrect to do so, but one thing is the meaning and use intended by the dictionary and the other is the one you find in daily usage. Maybe *allí* is used to refer to distant places by other people, but that doesn't make it correct.

Comment: well, maybe just as people said there are minor differences but it is not important.

Comment: This is very enlightening to me.  I had a Mexican (teenage) friend explain the distinction to me once, but the account she provided was very different: *ahí* is to reference a place that can be seen, *allí* is for a place that cannot be seen, and *allá* is a Latin American synonym for *allí*. I suppose that was inaccurate, or I probably misunderstood her.

Answer (score 13):

This can be explained with the three grades of demonstratives and of verbal persons:

1. Primera persona: **Esta** cosa ***aquí*** está **cerca de mí**.
2. Segunda persona: **Esa** cosa ***ahí*** está **cerca de ti**.
3. Tercera persona: **Aquella** cosa ***allí*** está **cerca de él** (o de otra persona; o sea, ni de ti ni de mí).

The *acá* and *allá* versions are less precise.  You might in English say over here or around there.  *Por acá* is around here, *por allá* is over there somewhere. There is no **ahá* version for euphonious reasons; people use *por ahí* to mean out there somewhere, as though it were the *-á* version of the middle (2ª persona) degree.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little addition to the existing good answers:

I believe that both `allá` and `acá` both originally were used in a similar way to the English `thither` and `hither` respectively (i.e. `to there` or `to here`), but this is not longer strictly required in modern Spanish grammar, as in modern English.

Currently, `allá` is typically used to mean `over there`, with a sense of remoteness beyond that of `allí`. It should be noted however that `acá` is used rather more rarely, and when it is, it still tends to retain its original meaning of `hither`.