# ¿"Ahí" y "allí" son distinguibles cuando usadas en países donde se usa mayormente el yeísmo?

Tags: yeísmo

La pronunciación me parece muy similar, y me pregunto se en la conversación normal se las pueden distinguir o si hay artificios o sinónimos que se usan para llegar a los mismos objetivos.

Comment: ¿Qué quisiste decir con atingir?

Comment: "To reach", pero probablemente me equivoqué y es una palavra del portugués.

Answer (score 6):

El [yeísmo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo) consiste en pronunciar la "ll" como "y", según la pronunciación regional de "y", ya que esta varía en algunas zonas.

En cualquiera de las pronunciaciones de "y" son sonidos completamente distintos, pero vamos a ver en detalle la pronuncación más común de "y", que es /j/, como "yes" en inglés o "ja" en alemán, y que además puede ser la más dudas pueda generar, puesto que en el yeísmo con la pronunciación rioplatense queda muy claro.
"Ahí" se diria "aí", mientras que "allí" quedaría como "ayí", absolutamente distinguibles.

Puedes escucharlos WordReference:

- [Ahí](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=ah%C3%AD)
- [Allí](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=all%C3%AD)

Comment: Son muy distinguibles en otras pronunciaciones que no el yeísmo, como en WordReference (que usa la pronunciación de España), pero me parecen poco distinguibles cuando hay yeísmo. La diferencia seria entre "ahí" y "ayí".

Comment: @obvio171 Lo siento, pero no te he entendido bien. En WordReference usan la pronunciación de España con yeísmo. Es lo que te he dicho mi respuesta precisamente, son distintos los sonidos "ahí" y "ayí". Aislando, uno suena "í", y otro es "yí".

Comment: @JoulSauron puede que obvio171 esté confundiendo el yeísmo que se refiere al cambio fonético que provoca que *ll* y *y* se confundan al ser pronunciadas. La *h* de *ahí* no se ve afectada para nada, por favor incluye la explicación de yeísmo, para aclarar posibles confusiones, ya que el usuario pregunta por el yeísmo. Saludos!

Comment: @Amedio, hecho, gracias, viendo otros comentarios me he dado cuenta de que el preguntador puede que no tenga claro en qué consiste el yeísmo.

Comment: Si claramente me confundí sobre que es el yeísmo. Pensé que significava la pronuncia de la "ll" como "y" de "yes", o "caballo" => "cabaio" como el ejemplo de @leonbloy. En este caso los sonidos serian como "aí" y "aií" y me parece que es más como una diferencia de la duracción de la "i". Quizás suficiente para nativos distinguieren, pero no tan claro para mi (como "o" y "ö" son absolutamente diferentes en aleman y todavía confunden hablantes de pt-BR).

Comment: [This answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/109/1126) seems to interpret "yeísmo" the same way as I did: "in other regions, ll and y have merged to /ʝ/ ('yeísmo')". Is it incorrect?

Comment: @obvio171 look at the bottom line comment, it says that in Río de la Plata they have yeísmo with their pronunciation of "y", so it's the same as what I said.

Answer (score 1):

No  hay mucha posibilidad de confusión, la diferencia es bastante notable cuando se usa el yeísmo (como aquí: Buenos Aires, Argentina). Sí puede ocurrir una pronunciación similar en algunas zonas (como algunas regiones del interior de Argentina) en las que la '*elle*' se pronuncia muy parecido a la '*i*' (*caballo* => '*cabaio*').

Comment: Esto es lo que quería decir con la pregunta. Se hace algo especial para evitar confusión en estes lugares donde se pronuncia "cabaio"? O el contexto es suficiente?

Answer (score 0):

si, es muy notable cuando alguien esta pronuciando "ahi" en lugar de "alli". Por ejemplo en Argentina - alli van a notar la falta del 'll' - 100% garantia.. Pero tambien la semantica entre los dos e diferente. Tu sabes - ahi se usa para distancias no tan lejanas, y alli - distancias muy muy lejanas. Si usas 'ahi' en lugar de 'alli' esto provoca una confusión

Comment: Sí, en Argentina es muy notable la diferencia porque la "ll" se habla muy distintamente, pero cuando se la habla con yeísmo, me parece que la diferencia entre "ahí" e "allí" es solo la duración del sonido de "i", lo que la hace muy sutil.