# Usage of the word acullá

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, arcaísmos, deixis

WordReference translates [acullá](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=acull%C3%A1) as "yonder." Is this a word that was only used in the past, or is it still used in modern Spanish today? If so, what regions does it appear in and how is it used?

Comment: in Spain I've never heard that word, though it exists for RAE

Comment: I've just heard (more exactly read) in fairy tales and similar stories.

Comment: This word is from old Castillian. It's difficult to hear that expression in our times. Also, as César correctly says, I always hear it as that way: "por aquí, por allá, por acullá".

Comment: My olders relatives also use it, eastern region of Spain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have said, this is not a commonly spoken word, but is found mostly in poetry and writing, perhaps especially used in folk and children tales. I would use "*acá y acullá*" as the equivalent of "*hither and yon*".

As an aside, The RAE defines "[acullá](http://dle.rae.es/acull%C3%A1)" as

> 1. adv. l. A la parte opuesta de quien habla. U. en contraposición a adverbios demostrativos de cercanía, como aquí o acá, y menos
>      frecuentemente a los de lejanía, como allí o allá, de los que puede
>      ser un intensivo.

So "l(ocative?) adverb. To the opposite part of the speaker. Used opposite to adverbs that demonstrate closeness, such as "aquí" or "acá", and less frequently to those of farness, such as "allí" or "allá", of which it can be an intensifier.

Comment: Just to update this answer, the new version of the DRAE defines the word as: _"**adverbio demostrativo culto.** Allá o más allá. U. en contraposición a adverbios demostrativos de cercanía, como aquí o acá, y también a los de lejanía, como allí o allá, cuyo significado puede intensificar."_

Comment: @Charlie interesting that they list it as *culto*, it has always sounded rural to me (based on who I know uses it in actual speech).

Answer (score 6):

I remember hearing `acullá` from my grandmother long time ago. She was looking for her comb everywhere in the house. My mother asked her:

> ¿Qué pasa? (What's wrong?)

And my grandmother answered:

> No puedo encontrar mi peine aquí, allá ni **acullá**! (I can't find my comb here, there and **yonder**[?]!)

So my best guess is that `acullá` means `más allá` (**over there** maybe).

Answer (score 3):

Spanish has six demonstrative adverbs.  In order from nearest to farthest, they are *aquí*, *acá*, *ahí*, *allí*, *allá*, *acullá*.  English has just three: *here*, *there*, *yonder*.  That's why it translated it as *yonder*, as they are both the farthest from the speaker (incidentally, being from the [US] South, I use *yonder* in regular speech and so while *allí* sits on a grey area between my English *there/yonder*, *allá* and *acullá* would always be *yonder* for me).

Can't speak for other countries, but you will hear *acullá* ocasionally in the north of Spain (Asturias, especially).

Answer (score 1):

It's a word only found in books and cartoons.

[Her's an example in "Alice in Wonderland":](http://vimeo.com/45091297#t=1090s)

> - Oye ven, ¿Por dónde está la reina?
> - A veces por aquí y a veces por acá. Pero como yo soy gente importante siempre entro por acullá.