# "Aquí" and "acá" regional differences

Tags: diferencias-regionales, adverbios, deixis

In Spain I learned *aquí, allí, allá,* but in Costa Rica it all seems to become *acá*. Am I not remembering the Castellano correctly or does this differentiation not exist in Latin America?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spain *acá* is not typically used. So you probably learned the Spanish from Spain where we use *aquí*, *allá* and *allí* as you said.

I believe the word *acá* is very common in Latin America countries, and has the same meaning as *aquí*.

Comment: It might not be as usual as in other Spanish speaking countries, but it is indeed used.

Comment: @Gorpik Never heard

Comment: As it was explained to me in Madrid aqui....alli............alla. Sorry I don't have the accents.  In Costa Rica it seems to be aca....aca.............aca

Answer (score 4):

"Aquí" and "Acá" have the same meaning. The same for "Allí" and "Allá".

We use "Aquí/Acá" when you're talking about a position near to you, or maybe your own position. In the other hand, "Allí/Allá" is for pointing a position far from you.

For example:

- *Aquí/Acá fue donde lo vi por última vez.*
- *Esta silla de aquí/acá es de hace 5 años.*
- *Vamos a comer allá/allí*
- *Ese de allá/allí es a quien buscas*

Comment: I'm from Chile, and this is how we use this words

Comment: There is a slight difference.  _acá_ and _allá_ may be used comparatively, whereas _aquí_ and _allí_ may not.  Hence _más acá/allá_ but not _más aquí_.

Answer (score 2):

I was taught - by a Colombian - that *aquí* is more proximal than *acá*.  That is, if something is in the general vicinity, but not at arm's length, one would use *acá*.  If it was easily reachable, one would use *aquí*. (Exactly where the boundary lies is a bit fuzzy).

Is this the case in Colombia, but not elsewhere?

Comment: En España no: _acá_ no se usa.

Answer (score 2):

As the RAE definitions compared in [this other answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/894/11102) show, both words have the same meaning. However, from the questions and comments it is clear that in some regions one is preferred over the other.

By using Google trends (thanks [@ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/ukemi) for this find), which shows what people are searching for, we can notice that:

- *aquí* is overwhelmingly preferred in [Spain](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=ES&q=aqu%C3%AD,ac%C3%A1)
- *aquí* and *acá* have mixed usage in hispanoamerica, with *aquí* being more popular overall but *acá* getting more common the further south you go
- [Argentina](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=AR&q=aqu%C3%AD,ac%C3%A1) is the only country where *acá* is more common than *aquí*

---

Since the language evolves here is the result of [Google trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=aqu%C3%AD,ac%C3%A1) as of May/2019

[image]

In the particular case of Argentina, again according to Google trends the preference for *acá* has [not been always the same](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=AR&q=aqu%C3%AD,ac%C3%A1) and around 2012 *aquí* was more common in searches.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. So Argentina is really the odd one out as I thought. Curiously we do prefer *ahí* in expressions like *ahí vamos* (though mostly reduced to something like *ay*).